# Is file.read() guaranteed to read the entire file?

Tags: python, text

The docs for `file.read()` say:

```
    Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
    may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.
```

Does this mean that `file.read()` isn't *guaranteed* to always return the entire contents of a text file, even though it most likely will?
If so, what would be the correct way to read an entire text file?

Comment: For clarification, which docs are you looking at? If online docs, can you provide a link? If a docstring, which docstring?

Comment: Part of why I ask is that the file object implementation is different on different Python versions, and there are multiple file implementations even on the same Python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "files" that are not regular files, if you have *specifically turned on* the mode where `file.read()` doesn't try to read everything, then `file.read()` might not read everything.

The docs specify non-blocking mode. Non-blocking mode is a mode that can be set on a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) in Unix, that only has an effect for "files" that represent sockets, pipes, or other communication devices. In non-blocking mode, if you try to read more data than is currently available, the file will give you what it has instead of waiting until enough data arrives.

Comment: So is there a way through Python to turn on non-blocking mode? Or is it an OS configuration?

Comment: @AvivCohn: [`os.set_blocking`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.set_blocking) and [`socket.socket.setblocking`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking), among other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Non blocking mode isn't something you'd typically use if you want the entire file, since the point of nonblocking is to get whatever data is available on the I/O you're waiting for, typically some async stream that may or may not have anything in it.

If it's a plain text file, you'd do something like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
         # something with a line of text here
         print(line)
```